# powershell write to file

Tags: powershell, user-interface, streamwriter

I've written a GUI for making changes in AD and I need every action logged. This GUI is used by multiple users at once and writes to  one file but only first person that writes to the log file can actually write to it. Everyone else has access denied.
I'm using streamwriter like this.

```
$File = "$LogPath\$LogDate.log"
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $File
$stream.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------")
$stream.WriteLine("$LogTime $ExecUser | Set expire date for user $setenddateuser to $usernewenddate")
$stream.close()
```

What am I doing wrong here that the handle for this file is not released for someone else to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ACL commands helped to fix the issue as the newly created file was lacking perrmissions for write for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a stream basically blocks the access or the creation of other streams for any files, unless  it's al xlsx in sharemode, what I do with the log similar logs is to use add-content.

I.e:

```
Add-content -value "test" -path $logRoute
```

Sorry for any typos, I'm on my cell atm. But that should fix your issue

Comment: Hi, This did not helped as I still get Access denied to the file. I would need something like open file write to it and close without ending the powershell script itself as its a part of GUI so another person could write to this file also using the same GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a fine-grained .NET mutex? Each time you need to log a message, lock the mutex, use `Add-Content` to append the message, then release the mutex. That should make sure the file is never opened multiple times simultaneously, which is almost certainly the cause of your problem.

[Here's an article on almost exactly this issue.](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/09/30/using-mutexes-to-write-data-to-the-same-logfile-across-processes-with-powershell/)

Comment: Hi, I've tried that but still failed. My code looks like that now: `$mtx = New-Object System.Threading.Mutex($false, "TestMutex")
If ($mtx.WaitOne(1000)){
Add-Content -path "$LogPath\$LogDate temp.log" -value "----------------------------------------------------"
Add-Content -path "$LogPath\$LogDate temp.log" -value "$LogTime $ExecUser | Set expire date for user $setenddateuser to $usernewenddate"
[void]$mtx.ReleaseMutex()
}
$mtx.Dispose()` and of course I get access denied.

Comment: Are you sure all the users involved actually have access to the file in question? Also, just out of paranoia, try removing the `|` character in your message.

Comment: Also, try adding Global\ to the start of your mutex name to make sure the mutex is visible across all logon sessions.

Comment: I've removed | from text and olso added global and it did not changed anything. :(

Comment: Just to make it all clear. I have a Virtual Machine that is connected to AD to which 7 users are logging in with they're own credentials and ps1 script is located on they're desktop. They run it and it stays open whole day. while taking any actions logs are supposed to be saved to a file on a d: drive that is accessible to everyone. File name is the current date so everyone is supposed to write to the same file. But when first person writes to it no one else can append it.

Comment: And all the copies of the script run on the same machine, correct?

Comment: Are you still opening a stream to the file? If so, remove or comment out that part.

Comment: Yes all are run on same machine. and I'm not using stream anymore. I've also tried to open a separate script that does the logging part and exit it and still access denied.  I'm using this line to start logging script invoke-expression -Command "D:\do_not_change\files\log.ps1" and at the end of it I put exit to force end of the script. Still does not work :(

Comment: Ok. Did some digging and it turns out that when a new file is created with powershell it only gets perrmissions for user that started the script so no one is even able to open it. Is there any way to create a file that has full access for everyone?

Comment: Create the file without using PowerShell, or modify its ACL using Get-Acl, Set-Acl, and the various ACL methods so that everyone has access.

Comment: Yes thats what I did I've used ACL and now everything is fine. I cannot believe how stupid the issue actually was ... Thank you for your help :)

Comment: (On SO, it's considered good form to either accept an existing answer or post your own and accept it once the problem is solved, so people know how it was fixed)